# Average calculator Fatal Exception

Tags: android, loops, average, handler, logcat

I am really new at programming. I am trying to run a simple average calculator and getting a force close, this is what the logcat is showing. I am running android studio version 2.3.3

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vu.gradingapp, PID: 6312
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:794)
    at com.vu.gradingapp.AverageActivity$1.onClick(AverageActivity.java:37)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The code i am using is as follow

```
public class AverageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editmanner, editinstances, editshortstance, editstrikes, editboxingskills, editknocks, editkicks, editResults;
Button btnResults;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.average_page);
    editmanner =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    editinstances =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    editshortstance = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    editstrikes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
    editboxingskills = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    editknocks = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText13);
    editkicks = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
    editResults = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText15);
    btnResults = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    btnResults.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, results;
    first=Integer.valueOf(editmanner.getText().toString());
    second=Integer.valueOf(editinstances.getText().toString());
    third=Integer.valueOf(editshortstance.getText().toString());
    fourth=Integer.valueOf(editstrikes.getText().toString());
    fifth=Integer.valueOf(editboxingskills.getText().toString());
    sixth=Integer.valueOf(editknocks.getText().toString());
    seventh=Integer.valueOf(editkicks.getText().toString());
    results=(first+second+third+fourth+fifth+sixth+seventh)/7;
    editResults.setText(String.valueOf(results));
}
    });


}
public void knowtheresults (View view) {
    String button_text;
    button_text = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
    if (button_text.equals("Summary")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (button_text.equals("Back")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

WHat am I doing wrong :D

Thanks Guys

Comment: Error says you cannot convert `""` value to number. So use `0` instead of number is blank.

Comment: I thin your problem is that you are doing the `Integer.valueOf()` on an empty string.

Comment: I suggest you learn at least basics of Java before starting with Android, otherwise you will be getting problems like that all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says you cannot convert "" value to number Its a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. So use 0 instead of number is blank first check if edittext is blank than set its value to 0

```
int first;
if(editmanner.getText().toString().equals("")){
first = 0
}else{
first = Integer.valueOf(editmanner.getText().toString());
}
```

do this for your all int variables.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with such verification for each int variable:

```
if (editmanner().toString().isEmpty())
   first = 0;
else
   first = Integer.parseInt(editmanner().toString());
```

Since you have `int` variables (not `Integer`) it is preferable to use `parseInt` instead `valueOf`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I just filled in the textedits with (0) and now is working. Please apologize for my silly questions.

Is there any way to hide this zeros on the textview so it shows blanks.

Comment: You don't need to fill edittexts with 0. Just leave it empty and make verification, I provided sample in my answer

Answer (score -1):

> **java.lang.NumberFormatException**
>   Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

The logcat already stated what is the cause of the crash. One or all of your `EditText` has empty string. To convert string to Integer, the string must be numeric(0,1,2 etc). You need to set EditText with numeric value (eg: 0).